# Visual Studio Code, interactive matplotlib plots with Jupyter widgets - Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-lab

I do not know why but when I run jupyter through VS code, the `%matplotlib widget` does not display anything. When I plot a graph, it only shows a line like :

```
Canvas(toolbar=Toolbar(toolitems=[('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home', 'home'),
       ('Back', 'Back to previous …
```

This does not happen when I run Jupyter Lab / notebook in the browser. The line magic works perfectly and I get a plot which I can pan, zoom etc. Does anyone have any idea about how to fix this? It's the only thing which is stopping me to switch to VS Code fully.

VS Code
MacOS 10.15 Catalina
Python 3.7.7